# What command would I use to run a cron job on a file not in public_html

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a php file which I want to be executed every 15 minutes. I have the cron job set up already. I just want to know what command I would use?

My file is located in `~/app/example/myfile.php`. So you can't access it through a URL. Otherwise I would have just used `wget -q -O /dev/null "URL"`

Answer (score 0):

In your crontab it'd be

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * php /path/to/file.php
```